# How to show correct Content creation date for photos/files in Finder

Tags: macos, finder, photos, preview, filesystem

How do I see the correct Content creation date in Finder?

I know from looking at the metadata on my phone (which the photos are synced with) that they should contain the correct date. About 2100 files in my photos folder are showing the same wrong date.

[image: Screenshot of the issue with a Finder search showing all files in the folder with the same exact creation date]

As you can see in the filename tooltip in the screenshot, a few of the files has another creation date than shown in finder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes Finder seems to not show the correct date that is saved in the photos/files. To »update« the files to show the correct Content created date you just need to open and close the files:

1. Mark the files and open them (I used Preview). Remember how many files you selected.

I did it in batches of ~500 on my 2015 Macbook Pro, which went smooth; if you're running an older mac, try with less and see how it goes.

2. Finder might give you a warning about opening »x number of files«, press OK.
3. They should now open in the same window in Preview. Wait for all the files to open. If you've remembered the number of files you selected to open, you can keep an eye on the number under the filename in Preview; it should show you »X documents« which is the number of files opened.

[image]

4. Close Preview.
5. The files should now be updated with the correct Content created date in Finder.

If this didn't work, I'd suggest to search for other solutions using Exiftool to update the files metadata from Exif data, if it contains the correct creation time.

[image]